# jQuery Error: xxx is Not a Function

Tags: jquery

This has been driving me crazy. I keep receiving **"TypeError: $(".yoxview").yoxview is not a function".**

Any clue what is wrong with my formatting or logic?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.yoxview').yoxview({
                skin: "top_menu",
                dataUrl: "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=decemberists&aq=f",
                thumbnailsOptions: {
                    setTitles: true,
                    thumbnailsClass: "thumbnail"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Most likely the `.yoxview` plugin is not properly loaded when you call it.

Comment: What makes you think `$(...).yoxview` should be defined?

Comment: Oooh... [this](http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/) yoxview, right?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I didn't think of that. So it may not be my logic, it may be the fact the issue is happening prior to this being loaded and the yoxview not existing.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Correct Sir. Been trying to get it to work and have been pulling my hair out.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - You were correct. I got it loaded and the error went away, yet i have a new error to troubleshoot now hehe "TypeError: p.children is not a function".

Comment: @ExplosionPills - write it as an answer and i will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `.yoxview` plugin is not properly loaded when you call it.

Make sure that you are including the appropriate script *before* you attempt to call it, for example:

```
<script src="yoxview.js"></script>
<script>
   $("#elem").yoxview();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any other libraries in your code, ie. Prototype? 
If so, the "$" will clash. do.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.yoxview').yoxview({
            skin: "top_menu",
            dataUrl: "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=decemberists&aq=f",
            thumbnailsOptions: {
                setTitles: true,
                thumbnailsClass: "thumbnail"
            }
        });
    });
```

Also, instead of using '.yoxview' trying assigning an ID to that same element and using:

```
$('#yournewID').yoxview
```